# ¿Cómo sumar strings en PHP? Es decir "+=" de JavaScript

Tags: php, string, concatenación

En *JavaScript* existe esto, `+=` para ir añadiendo valores después de los que ya fueron añadidos.

Lo que quiero hacer es un `forEach` de un array que añada los elementos del array a un string.

De esta manera se puede **sumar strings** como se hacía en *JavaScript* pero en *PHP*.

¿Hay alguna equivalencia en *PHP*?

PHP:

```
$numeros = array("uno ","dos ","tres ");
$numerosencadena = "";
foreach ($numeros as $valor) {
    // Aquí necesito ir añadiendo los valores en $numeroscadena
    // para que quede algo así $numeroscadena = "uno dos tres "
}
unset($valor);
```

En *JavaScript* sería algo así:

```
var numeros = [];
var numeroscadena;

numeros.forEach(valor => {
    numeroscadena+= valor;
)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

En PHP el equivalente por el que preguntas es este: `.=` y se llama **[operador de asignación sobre concatenación](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php)**, el cual añade el argumento del lado derecho al argumento en el lado izquierdo. Eso sí, la variable debe existir antes de usarlo, debes cuidar eso o tu log de errores se llenará de mensajes *PHP Notice:  Undefined variable*, aunque funcionará igual, no uses la variable sin antes declararla vacía o con un valor inicial deseado.

En el ejemplo que pones el código sería así:

```
$numeros = array("uno ","dos ","tres ");
$numerosencadena = "";
foreach ($numeros as $valor) {
    // Aquí necesito ir concatenando los valores en $numeroscadena
    //para que queda algo así $numeroscadena = "uno dos tres "
    $numerosencadena .=$valor;
}

echo $numerosencadena;
```

**Salida:**

```
uno dos tres
```

---

### Otra posibilidad

En el caso concreto de arrays puedes usar [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) el cual sirve precisamente para *unir elementos de un array en una sola cadena*.

`implode` recibe dos parámetros: el primero es el valor que se pegará al final de cada valor del array, y el segundo es el array en sí.

En este caso, una línea de código bastaría para hacer lo que quieras. Aquí indicas que quieres cada valor del array separado por un espacio en blanco: `" "`:

```
$conImplode = implode(" ", $numeros);
echo $conImplode;
```

**Salida:**

```
uno dos tres
```

Comment: Aunque todas las respuestas me ayudan a conseguir el resultado final que es "uno dos tres", tu respuesta incluye la equivalencia del `+=` y su explicación, que es lo que solicitaba.

Comment: @EmilianoPamont me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.

Comment: Y a todo esto creo que voy a terminar usando para este caso `implode`, pero saber el `.=` me va a resolver varios líos que he tenido por no conoce la equivalencia en php

Comment: Conocer este operador es de mucha utilidad. Por ejemplo, yo lo uso mucho cuando hay que escribir código en parte HTML y en parte PHP, para evitar una sintaxis ilegible, que hace daño a la vista (como es la horrible mezcla HTML/PHP abriendo y cerrando bloques), inicio una variable `$html` dentro de PHP y le voy concatenando todos los elementos a dicha variable imprimiéndola al final. Este operador saca a uno de muchos apuros y ayuda a escribir código más claro @EmilianoPamont.

Answer (score 6):

Se llama *[concatenación<sup>1</sup>](https://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php)*, y se hace con el punto `.`

Ejemplo:

```
$nombre = 'Emiliano';
$apellido = 'Pamont';

$nombre_completo = $nombre . $apellido;

echo $nombre_completo; //Retorna: Emiliano Pamont
echo 'Hola ' . $nombre //Retorna: Hola Emiliano
```

Para lo que dices del `foreach` sería algo como lo siguiente:

```
<?php 

$numeros = array("uno ","dos ","tres ");
$numerosencadena = "";

foreach ($numeros as $valor) {
    $numerosencadena .= $valor;
}

echo $numerosencadena; //Salida: uno dos tres
?>
```

Notas:

1. *Concatenación*: [PHP: Operadores para strings](https://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: No se me había ocurrido, aunque será funcional, quiero saber si existe alguna equivalencia al `+=` de javascript

Comment: este codigo no da la salida que se pide en la pregunta

Comment: @Alfredo ¿Por qué no?

Comment: "Aquí necesito ir añadiendo los numeros en $numeroscadena"...

Comment: @AndySamuel por que me da esta salida uno uno dos uno dos tres si checas la pregunta la salida que pide solo es uno dos tres, sin que los valores se repitan

Comment: Ya, revisé el código y lo tenía bien de primero. Te da esa salida porque colocas echo dentro del foreach y no fuera... @Alfredo edité el código, puedes colocar ".=" y te hace el resultado que quieres.

Comment: Probé el codigo en alguna de las ediciones y sí funcionó, concuerdo con Andy en que tal vez el `echo` estaba dentro del  `forEach`

Answer (score 5):

Sí, existe una forma similar al `+=`, sería:

```
$numeros = array("uno ","dos ","tres ");
$numerosencadena = "";
foreach ($numeros as $valor) {
    $numerosencadena .= $valor;
}
$numerosencadena = trim($numerosencadena);
```

El `trim` para eliminar el espacio en blanco del final del ciclo, así que es opcional.